# Elementary OS boot skipped Grub

Tags: dual-boot, elementary-os

I've just installed a fresh elementary os freya to dual boot with my windows 10 but when I startup my computer it goes straight into elementary os and skipped the grub bootloader screen

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to hold **shift** key when booting up?

If there is no Windows, boot elOS, open terminal and execute `sudo update-grub` and reboot

Then you should see it

And read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188128)

Comment: guys, turned out it didn't need to do anything, it suddenly started to boot fine into grub. I think it's because I did some updates and some of them fixed or updated grub for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try keep pressing up/down keys when your system boots, if there is no effect try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

And then click on **recommended repair**

then follow the steps according to the instruction.

And then if you don't get the option of both OS, there should be issue of UFI boot.

Reference link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair